# Night Light Is Not Working

Tags: release-juno, lenovo, nightlight

I have installed elementary OS [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) one week ago and i tried to enable night light but its not working, even in manual or sunset ~ sunrise time.
how can i fix it ? did anyone else get this weird problem?

Comment: i have same issue, first day night light is working, second day it's broken.
night light indicator showing up in wingpanel, but not working. well just install redshift on appcenter, it's working at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
Wingpanel Nightlight Indicator
[image: Wingpanel Nightlight Indicator]
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-nightlight

Answer (score 0):

My problems regarding the night light is due to the use of dual graphical cards (optimus technology with nvidia) on my notebook, all I needed to do is to install the latest nvidia driver and it worked on the next reboot.

There are lots of details about that, you can either install bumblebee or `nvidia-prime`, the latter I currently use. To make usage of that you have to type in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

Take a note, however, that this might be dangerous and you have the chance to get a black screen on the next reboot; in order to fix the problem you just log in another tty (Ctrl+alt+FX where x belongs to [1, 9] and remove everything related to nvidia.